# VS Code, Embedded language syntax highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have been working on a VS Code extension for the Telemark Assembler which is an old DOS table driven assembler. i.e. it supports many different processors. I'm at the point where I have syntax highlighting for several supported processors working and problem matching is working as well.

In package.json the proper syntax highlighter can be automatically selected by adding the processor name to the file name, i.e. "myFile.6502.asm" an example entry is below. A friend just asked if it would be possible to select the correct highlighter via a flag in the source file.

I thought about this a bit and it occurred to me that this might work if the 'flag' was a tag that VS Code would see as marking an embedded language. I have done a fair bit of searching so far and most of what I have found deals with JavaScript being embedded in another language and is along the lines of "oh is this is marked as JavaScript then use this syntax highlighter" I have not found anything pertaining as to how to create your own embedded language marker (if that is the correct term.)

Thanks for any tips.

```
            {
            "id": "TASM-1802",
            "aliases": [
                "TASM_1802 Assembly"
            ],
            "extensions": [
                ".asm",
                ".1802.asm"
            ],
            "configuration": "./TASM.configuration.json"
        },
```

Comment: I'm way out of my league, but looking at [Scala Metals extension](https://github.com/scalameta/metals-vscode/blob/7984435e8e694655bdf7ea84faeeb38c35df6002/src/extension.ts#L314), I traced it back to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node/blob/998933dca41b70f85e963f31f225220b54044548/protocol/src/common/protocol.ts#L95). If you include some of those configuration settings in your extension I think you will get the result you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The example you linked to is for a language server which is a few steps beyond what I am doing. As I understand it a language server lets your extension do things that require a contextual understanding of the source. I'm just after syntax highlighting at this point. 

From the example though does hint at there being a "TextDocument.languageId" which can be used. I'll try to do some research on that.